# VBA Code: Skipping column entries if already filled

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 Sheets: `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, ...

`Sheet1` has all the data, it has a Column `R3` to `R17` which is what I want.

`Sheet2` has three columns, Static Column --- This will have a formula(`=+Sheet1!R3 etc till R17`) Col1 ---(same as Static Column) Will show the value of `R3-R17` (but later only values will remain in this column not the formula) Col2 --- This will be next column where I want values.

On Sheet2, I want is that whenever I press the shortcut for Macro..

It should, copy the formula from that Static Column, paste it in Col1, so Col1 can get entries from Sheet1, `R3-R17` column.....

then when I press the shortcut button again,

It should now copy the formula from the static column, see if Col1 is filled, if filled, put it on Col2 so Col2 now can get entries from `Sheet1 (R3-R17)` and keep only the REAL values in Col1.

Then when I press the shortcut button again,

It should now copy the formula from the static column, see if Col1,Col2 is filled, if filled, put it on Col3 so Col3 can get entries from `Sheet1 (R3-R17)` and keep only the REAL values in Col2.

I am almost half done, but cant make the macro switch to the next column ..

```
Sub PlayerSheet()
    Dim LC As Long, r As Range
    Set r = Application.InputBox("click in the column to copy", Type:=8)
    LC = r.Column
    Columns(LC + 1).Insert
    Columns(LC).Copy
    Cells(1, LC + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Columns(LC).Copy
    Cells(1, LC).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  End Sub
```

Comment: Add your tried code (as you half done) and tell us about your problem on that ;).

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to answer this question... but this is my first time with this site, i dont see the option of putting additional information without editing my original question...

But here is the code :

```
    Sub PlayerSheet()
    Dim LC As Long, r As Range
    Set r = Application.InputBox("click in the column to copy", Type:=8)
     LC = r.Column
     Columns(LC + 1).Insert
     Columns(LC).Copy
       Cells(1, LC + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
      Columns(LC).Copy
      Cells(1, LC).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      End Sub
```

Now, it does not do what i intend it to do ... but my work is half done.

What it does is, it asks me to select the cell i want to copy.. and then copy the whole column and put it in the next column with the formulas and then, paste back only the "values" in the column where it copied it from.

What i want is that it should be fully automatic, it should not ask me to select the cell which i want to copy. It should automatically select the last column, copy it, paste it in next with formulas and then paste only the values in the column where it copied it from.

Comment: you have an `edit` grayed text below your questions tags, just click it and add your code in your question ;).

Comment: I have done that. But marked it as in my answer, can you see the whole thread and let me know how can i make the code better.

Comment: You can now `delete` this answer ;).